# No plotting by d3js when data is linked to a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, d3.js, plot, plotly

I'm trying the simplest plot (of any type) with data obtained from an external JSON file. I use `plotly.js`, which is an extension of d3js.

This is the part of interest:

```
var dates = [], scores = [];
var user_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/anton_tarasenko.json';
var item_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/';

$.getJSON(user_json, function (user) {
    $.each(user.submitted, function(i, item_id) {
        $.getJSON(item_json + item_id + '.json', function(item) {
            if (item.type == 'story') {
                scores.push(Number(item.score));
                dates.push(Number(item.time));
            }
        });
    });
});

var data = [{
    x: dates,
    y: scores,
    mode: 'lines+markers',
    type: 'scatter'
}];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

This returns an empty plot. But when I replace `x: dates` with `x: [1461189218, 1460844086, ... , 1427738937]` and `y: scores` with `y: [1, 154, ..., 1]` (output of `console.log(dates)` and `log(scores)`), it works fine.

So why does the library ignores references to arrays? I think I misuse variables, but not sure how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to do with the nature of asynchronous programming. As `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous all of your subsequent code is actually being executed before the scores or dates array have been populated.

For your code to work as intended you can methods could include moving all of your remaining code inside the callback (and call plot for each item) or using promises (and call plot once with all of your data). Using jQuery you can work with promises with relative ease.

```
var user_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/anton_tarasenko.json';
var item_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/';

// Main

getUser()
  .then(getScoresAndDates)
  .then(plot);

// Declarations
function all(arrayOfPromises) {
  return jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises).then(function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  });
}

function getUser() {
  return $.getJSON(user_json);
};

function getScoresAndDates(user) {

  var scoresAndDates = [];

  $.each(user.submitted, function(i, item_id) {
    scoresAndDates.push($.getJSON(item_json + item_id + '.json'));
  });

  return all(scoresAndDates);
}

function plot(result) {
  scoresAndDates = result
  .map(function(v){
    return v[0];
  })
  .filter(function(v) {
    return v.type == 'story';
  })

  var scores = scoresAndDates.map(function(v) {
    return v.score
  });
  var dates = scoresAndDates.map(function(v) {
    return v.time
  });

  var data = [{
    x: dates,
    y: scores,
    mode: 'lines+markers',
    type: 'scatter'
  }];

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an asynch problem. Try to place your code in the callback:

```
var dates = [], scores = [];
var user_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/anton_tarasenko.json';
var item_json = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/';
var ii = 0;
$.getJSON(user_json, function (user) {
  $.each(user.submitted, function(i, item_id) {
    $.getJSON(item_json + item_id + '.json', function(item) {

         ii++;
        if (item.type == 'story') {
            scores.push(Number(item.score));
            dates.push(Number(item.time));
            //check for last iteration
            if(ii === user.submitted.length){
            var data = [{
                x: dates,
                y: scores,
                mode: 'lines+markers',
                type: 'scatter'
                 }];
                Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
            }
        }


     });
  });
});
```

This is not a very elegant solution but it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot: it was async. I moved `newPlot` after `push`es, so now it redraws the plot each time it gets a new number.